# The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process. azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I have added a mastercard sdk to my asp.net core api. The call to api works fine on my local machine. But when deployed on azure it throws the above error.

I have tried everything.

I have attached a debugger to the live site. It throws error when I call 
SetAuthentication

```
public MatchType RequestCall(string consumerKey, string keyAlias, string keyPassword)
    {
        byte[] certificateBytes = GetCertificateStream();
        ApiConfig.SetAuthentication(new OAuthAuthentication(consumerKey, certificateBytes, keyAlias, keyPassword));
        ApiConfig.SetSandbox(true);

        RequestMap map = GenerateRequestMap();
        TerminationInquiryRequest response = TerminationInquiryRequest.Create(map);
        return GetMatchType(response);

    }



 public byte[] GetCertificateStream()
        {
            var resourceName = typeof(TerminationMatchInquiry).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()[0];//Get certificate resource name
            using (Stream CertStream = typeof(TerminationMatchInquiry).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                byte[] RawBytes = new byte[CertStream.Length];
                for (int Index = 0; Index < CertStream.Length; Index++)
                {
                    RawBytes[Index] = (byte)CertStream.ReadByte();
                }
                return RawBytes.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you Google your error message? It comes up with some promising results.

Comment: Oh yes. But still no luck

Comment: I'm surprised that even compiles. I can't find an overload of `OAuthAuthentication` that takes a byte array in the second argument. Have you tried using the path to your .p12 file instead of reading it out of resources?

Comment: Yes. I am getting bit close now. I think it is a timeout issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review the source of [MasterCard SDK](https://github.com/Mastercard/sdk-core-csharp) for C#, I found that, it will create an instance of X509Certificate2 when we invoke OAuthAuthentication. The error is caused in this line.

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(rawCertificateData, password, keyStoreFlags | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

In the Azure WebApp, if we try to use the certificate, we need to upload the certificate from the Azure portal. Add the WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with thumbprint value in the Azure WebApp application. More detail info please refer to [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/?v=17.23h).